# Generating username with combination of characters c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have below method to generate a username on 2 conditions: On `Page load` and on `refresh click`. While `Page load` it should return `Content` and on `refresh click` it should return `Json`. So I decided to hook up an `ActionResult` as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GenerateUName(string calltype)
{
     using (_db = new DBEntity())
     {
           const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
           int length = 10;
           var random = new Random();
           string uname = string.Empty;
           bool exists = true;
           int repeat = 0;
           while (exists && repeat < 5)
           {
               uname = Convert.ToString(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
               exists = _db.tblUsers.Any(u => u.UserName == uname);
               repeat++;
           }
           TempData["generatedUName"] = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(uname) ? uname : string.Empty;
           if (calltype == "action")
                 return Content(uname);
           return Json(new { username = uname, result = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

and in Page Load I receive it as

```
user.UserName = Convert.ToString(TempData["generatedUName"]);
```

But whenever I run this, I get `System.Char[]` as `json` response and `System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult` on `Page Load` above. How can I get a valid string here? The above code of generating random string was picked from some other post and it was of return type string but for me its getting different results. What changes I need to do in this case?

Comment: Try generate guid as username https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Dudi.. Good suggestion, but I wanted to try different approach this time.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `Convert.ToString(char[])`, which doesn't create a string in the way you might expect. It is doing the equivalent of `char[].ToString()` which gives you the type name `System.Char[]`.

The reason this is happening is that there is no overload of `Convert.ToString()` which accepts a `char[]` parameter, so it is calling the `Convert.ToString(object)` overload instead. The implementation of `Convert.ToString(object)` just returns `object.ToString()`.

Try this instead:

```
uname = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
```

i.e. use the [`String(char[])` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create the string.

Comment: Works cool buddy.. Yes.. In the post I took this from, it was `new string` instead of `Convert.ToString`.. I wasn't aware of this functionality, so I changed it to `Convert.ToString`.. But again when it returns `Content` to action, even though it has valid string, it will be received as `System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult` and am calling the method in action as below `model.UserName = Convert.ToString(GenerateUName("action"));`. Any idea why this is happening.. Json is working fine now..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Not sure, but it looks like a similar problem - there's no overload of Convert.ToString() that takes an `ActionResult` object.

Comment: Any suggestions on that as in which one to use instead of `Convert.ToString`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Perhaps you can cast it to `System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult` and then use the `.Content` property.